# Tor relay unable to be connected to

Tags: relays, raspberry-pi

Hi guys I have configured a Raspberry Pi to be run as a relay, however I am unable to connect to it.

Can any of you connect to it ? The name is Goblin500.

I have created a python library that should be able to make circuits on Tor, so far this has been successful but for some reason I can not connect to my own relay and am just trying to start pinpointing the issue.